# << is a C++ thing - java equivalent

Tags: java, c++

C++ has this sign `>>` so for example:

```
cin >> a >> b >> cp >> c
```

Does java have an equivalent to `>>` ?

Thank you

Comment: ["operator overloading"](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_overloading.html) (as in your C++ IOStreams example above) is a C++ thing.  I would argue it's a very *bad* thing (IMHO)...  Java *does*, however, allow ["method chaining"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), which is also illustrated in your example.

Comment: @prelic: This is where C/C++ doesn't apply.  The C language does not have the same streams as C++.  So get used to saying either C or C++.  For example, you can't say `stdin >> my_variable` in the C language.

Answer (score 4):

The c++ >> operator is equivalent to the Java Scanner class. Use this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
a = in.nextLine();
```

That should get you one line of user input. From there you can do b=a, cp=b, or whatever. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by >>. You see, << >> are overloaded operators, used for both bitwise shift operations and I/O.

Java has input, such as the Scanner class as mentioned by awolfe91, and output in the form of System.out.print("String goes here") (as opposed to cout << a).

Java also has the bitwise shift operator, which works, as far as I know, in exactly the same way as in C++ - << or >>.